# How to do regex between symbol and extract text?

Tags: vb.net

how do you extract to get between the equal sign the text ?
in order to get the title ?
I 'm new in coding and try to learn vb.net and some regex. :)

do you also how to get the trip text  and also the billed between the ####

```
===%Summary%===




Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.




### Trip:No/Yes | Billed:Yes/No ###
```

it would be very helpful for my first class tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```
      Dim test = decoder("====%Summary%====

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

### Trip:Yes| Billed:No###
")
Function decoder(final_subject As String)

      Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(?<==%)(.*?)(?=%=)")
      Dim match As Match = regex.Match(final_subject)
      If match.Success Then
          Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
      End If

      Dim regex2 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Trip:)(.*?)(?= )")
      Dim match2 As Match = regex2.Match(final_subject)
      If match2.Success Then
          Console.WriteLine(match2.Value)
      End If


      Dim regex3 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Billed:)(.*?)(?=#)")
      Dim match3 As Match = regex3.Match(final_subject)
      If match2.Success Then
          Console.WriteLine(match3.Value)
      End If


      Return match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim test = decoder("====%Summary%====

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

### Trip:Yes| Billed:No###
")
Function decoder(final_subject As String)

 
        Dim regex1 As Regex = New Regex("(?<====)(.*?)(?====)")
        Dim match As Match = regex1.Match(final_result)
        If match.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
        End If

        Dim regex1_1 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=##)(.*?)(?=##)")
        Dim match1_1 As Match = regex1_1.Match(final_result)

        Dim String_footer As String = match1_1.Value

        Dim regex2 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Trip:)(.*?)(?=B)")
        Dim match2 As Match = regex2.Match(String_footer)
        If match2.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(match2.Value)
        End If


        Dim regex3 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Billed:)(.*?)(?=#)")
        Dim match3 As Match = regex3.Match(final_result)
        If match3.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(match3.Value)
        End If


      Return (match,match2,match3)
```